# Seeking Python library to check validity of 3D polygon

Tags: python, geometry, software-recommendations, shapely, 3d

In the case of 2d polygons I have been using shapely:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
Polygon(points).is_valid
```

But for 3D polygons, shapely simply computes the validity in the x-y plane as described in their documentation:

> Coordinate sequences are immutable. A third z coordinate value may be
> used when constructing instances, but has no effect on geometric
> analysis. All operations are performed in the x-y plane.

Is there a Python library that can check for polygon validity in 3D given a Nx3 array of numpy points?

By validity I mean no self-intersections and holes.